# R: Strange tryCatch behavior on throwing a warning()

Tags: r, exception, try-catch

I came across an issue while using tryCatch in R. The following toy functions should help explain:

```
## Toy Function that throws a Stop error on being given 1 as input and halts execution
## Warning on being given 2 as input and returns 2
## for all other inputs just echoes it back.

f1=function(i){
          print("in f1")
          if(i==1){
            stop("Error: i=1 encountered")
            }else if (i==2){ 
            warning("Warning: i=2 encountered")
            print("line after warning was thrown")
            }else {
            print ("alls' ok")
            }
          print(paste0("Out of If condition: ",i))
          return(i)
        }


## function calls f1 to incite error or warning behavior.
        f2=function(i){
         print("in f2")
         tryCatch(
           {a=f1(i)},  ## {} or () are needed around the expression, else R throws an Error
                error=function(e){ 
                  stop(paste0("Error in f2  ",e));
                  print(e)
                  },
                warning=function(w){ 
                  print("back in f2 ");
                  #print(paste0("Warning = ",w))
                  }
              )
          print(paste0("contents of a= ",a))
        return(a)
         }
```

Now: The function behaves as expected for input !=2. 
But on giving 2 as input,

```
        > f2(2)
        [1] "in f2"
        [1] "in f1"
        [1] "back in f2 "
        [1] "contents of a= f2 hello"
        [1] "f2 hello"
```

the following things happen:

1. it doesnt run the line after the warning is thrown (i.e. `print("line after warning was thrown")` ). Since my `options('warn')` is set at `0` (default) I was expecting the function `f1` to run to the end before tryCatch catches the warnings. Here it seems its catching the warnings the moment it is thrown. Hence execution doesnt go to the lines following the throwing of the warning.
2. Also, the return value of the `f1` call in variable `a` is the last message in the warning block. Should it not be the output of `f1`

I find these two behaviors rather strange. 
Is my understanding of the bahavior of tryCatch flawed or Is it that I am doing something wrong?

Backstory: In my actual code where I encountered this behavior, `f1` happens to be a largish function which takes a hell lot of time to run.
What we noticed is that the variable capturing the return value of `f1('a')` would have a string of text in it instead of a dataframe.

Comment: I don't get the result you do, restart your r session and try again

Comment: You are correct on point 1. The execution of `f1` is stopped as soon as a warning is thrown. You likely have an object `a` defined in the global environment, with the value `"f2 hello"`. If you clean your workspace, you should have the error `object a not found` when calling `f2(2)`, since `f1` doesn't return anything and the object `a` is not defined anywhere.